# Autofill email address/contact info in UITextField similar to safari

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill

Is there a way to autofill textfields for content type other than password and username?

In my app I have a series of sign-up screens that include:

1. First screen with email+password text fields. Email text field is content type: email address, password field is content type password
2. second screen has First and last name, content types given name and family name respectively
3. third screen is the username, content type username.

The strong password generation on screen 1 works fine. However, the keyboard does not pop-up email address suggestions. The email and password ARE automatically being saved to the keychain once this screen is completed.

The first and last name fields do not suggest anything. I am expecting the keyboard to present suggestions for first and last name.

Finally, the username field does not suggest anything (as expected). It also does not save the username to the keychain. I assume this is because its on a separate screen from the password text field? I am okay with this.

Is there any sort of set-up required for the keyboard to provide suggestions for the first and last name OTHER than setting the textfield content type?

All of my textfields have the keyboard types set to default with the exception of the email address fields.

Something else I noticed:

The keyboard is presenting email autofill suggestions on our "forgot your password" screen where there is only a single textfield with emailaddress content type.

Here is the setup for all of my text fields:

[TextField Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQVB.jpg)